# stop instance in azure compute emulator

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I'm debugging a website that is hosted with an azure webrole. Its configured to run with two instances. Now I want to stop one of the emulator instances while debugging is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I blogged about this a while ago: [Controlling your instances in the Windows Azure Compute Emulator](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/controlling-your-instances-in-the-windows-azure-compute-emulator/). At the time of writing this article, I was using version 1.7 of the SDK. I noticed that, when using SDK 1.8, killing instances when debugging did work correctly.

So if you want to scale down in the emulator you'll need to run the following command referencing an updated ServiceConfiguration.csconf file (with Instances count = 1 instead of 2):

```
csrun.exe /update:<deployment-id>;<service-configuration-file>
```

You can also simulate a failure on one of your instances by killing a **WaIISHost.exe** process.

Comment: Thanks. I actually found yoour blogpost ans used some of it. I tried to kill one of the WaIISHost but that was not the way of doing it. Or at lease When I made a second request to the testing webpage, I was not directed to the second instance of the compute emulator.

Answer (score 0):

you can scale down to 1 instance or stop in the instances page

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/cloud-services/how-to-scale-a-cloud-service/

Comment: the OP is referring to the development emulator , not live.